# Video playing not working

Tags: php, video

I have a site for uploading and display video.  The video with format mov,  wmv,avi,3gp, mp4 was uploaded successfully at localhost or server—i.e. the files show up in the admin/user_video folder no problem. The problem right now is when i run the site to display:

Run at localhost:

1. video with format **mp4** and **3gp** -plays normaly
2. video with format **mov** -it plays, but only audio. You can hear the sound as the video plays but can't see the video itself.
3. video with format **wmv** and **avi** -not display anything

Run at server:

1. video with format **mp4** only -plays normaly
2. video with format **3gp** -it plays, but only audio. You can hear the sound as the video plays but can't see the video itself.
3. video with format **mov**, **wmv** and **avi** -not display anything

The video on server can be seen [here](http://sims.fkm.utm.my/testv.php). You can see only mp4 can play and 3gp play sound only.

Any ideas?Can anyone help me?

here my code:

```
<video width="230" height="200" controls>
  <source src="admin/user_video/<?php echo $readrow['videos'] ?>">
</video>
<p><?php echo $readrow['video_name']; ?></p>
```

and here code for valid extensions:

```
    $upload_dir = 'admin/user_video/'; // upload directory

    $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get video extension

    // valid video extensions
    $valid_extensions = array('mp4', 'avi', 'mov', 'wmv', '3gp'); // valid extensions

    // rename uploading video
    $vid = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not about PHP; first check server's content types.

An .htaccess file for Apache:

```
AddType video/3gpp .3gp
```